# Clustering in ArcGIS - Fixed size

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, matlab-mapping-toolbox

I want to do clustering of point data say buildings in an area to a fixed size for example each cluster should have 32x buildings. Can i do it in ArcGIS?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet for clustering algorithms is in the [open-source R](http://www.r-project.org/) software environment.  Specifically, R has a stochastic QT clustering algorithm in the `flexclust` package that allows you to specify a maximum radius of clusters.  In this example, I generated several points in a lake to use as sample data.  Then I specified a 500 m cluster radius.

---

[image]

---

```
library(rgdal)
library(flexclust) # Loads flexclust library.

# Read shapefile
shp = "C:/temp/points.shp"
myshp = readOGR(shp, layer = basename(strsplit(shp, "\\.")[[1]])[1]) 

# Create a dataframe to pass to qtclust
df = data.frame(myshp$coords.x1, myshp$coords.x2)

# Run the clustering with a cluster radius of 500m
cl1 = qtclust(df, radius = 500)

# Plot the results
plot(df, col=predict(cl1), xlab="", ylab="")

# Provides the row-to-cluster assignment information.
d = data.frame(cl=attributes(cl1)$cluster) 

# Add cluster ID to shapefile attributes
myshp$cluster = d$cl

# write to new shapefile
writeOGR(myshp, "C:/temp", "clustered_points", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```